# Checkboxes Not Saving to Database

Tags: php, wordpress, radio-button

In the function below, data in the text input is being saved to the database just as it is supposed to. The check boxes, however, are not staying checked and don't appear to be saving anything to the database. (The code is from a WordPress plugin I'm modifying to show or hide menu items based on a user's location.)

What am I doing wrong?

```
function option( $fields, $item_id ) {
    ob_start(); ?>
        <p class="field-visibility description description-wide">
            <label for="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
                <?php _e('Enter country code(s) separated by commas') ?>:
                <input
                    type="text" 
                    class="widefat code" 
                    id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" 
                    name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" 
                    value="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ) ); ?>" /></br>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id;?>"
                    name="menu-item-show-hide[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" 
                    value="hide" <?php checked( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'hide_show', true ), 'hide', true ); ?>
                />Hide from these locations.</br>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>"
                    name="menu-item-show-hide[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]"
                    value="show" <?php checked( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'hide_show', true ), 'show', true ); ?>
                />Only show to these locations.</br>
            </label>
        </p>
    <?php
    $fields[] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fields;
}
```

Here's what I'm using to update the data in the database:

```
function update_option_text( $menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', true );
    $new_meta_value = stripcslashes( $_POST['menu-item-visibility'][$menu_item_db_id] );

    if( '' == $new_meta_value ) {
        delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', $meta_value );
    }
    elseif( $meta_value !== $new_meta_value ) {
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', $new_meta_value );
    }
}

    function update_option_hide_show( $menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'hide_show', true );
    $new_meta_value = stripcslashes( $_POST['menu-item-visibility'][$menu_item_db_id] );

    if( '' == $new_meta_value ) {
        delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'hide_show', $meta_value );
    }
    elseif( $meta_value !== $new_meta_value ) {
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'hide_show', $new_meta_value );
    }
}
```

And the constructor:

```
function __construct() {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', array( &$this, 'edit_nav_menu_walker' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', array( &$this, 'option' ), 12, 2 );
        add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', array( &$this, 'update_option_text' ), 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', array( &$this, 'update_option_hide_show' ), 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'delete_post', array( &$this, 'remove_visibility_meta' ), 1, 3);
    } else {
        add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', array( &$this, 'visibility_check' ), 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'clear_gantry_menu_cache' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code which insert into database ?

Comment: @Thomas: Just added it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$new_meta_value = stripcslashes( $_POST['menu-item-visibility'][$menu_item_db_id] );` to `$new_meta_value = stripcslashes( $_POST['menu-item-show-hide'][$menu_item_db_id] );` did the trick. It's working perfectly now!

Thanks @Thomas for making me rethink how it was getting posted to the database.